# How to resize SimpleMDE textarea size?

Tags: javascript, simplemde

I use SimpleMDE on my website for simplifying the usage of `<textarea>` as a text editor.
When trying to customize it, I ran into one problem: I don't know how to resize the text editor.

For example, when inspecting the result of the SimpleMDE code on my website, I found out the default height for the text editor is `20rem`. I want it to be more than that.

I came up with one solution, but I consider it to be unreliable, since it is a method of my own, not a built-in one. I simply changed the CSS attributes for the `CodeMirror` class (as it is the container class for the text editor).

As you could probably guess though, I am looking for a built-in way to do this to avoid any problems and have it the intended way. So how do I do this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm interested too. P.s. SimpleMDE development appears stopped, but it has been forked with new fixes as https://github.com/Ionaru/easy-markdown-editor .

Comment: @Mort Nope, still overriding the `CodeMirror` CSS class :( Still works though